# Find if the sentence does not contains specific words

Tags: regex

i have a `regular expression` which find if the `sentence`s contains specific words

my query is:

```
(?=.*hello)(?=.*hi)(?=.*hey).*
```

but now i want to check if my `sentence` does not contains this words

i have tried:

```
(?=.*((?!hello).))(?=.*((?!hi).))(?=.*((?!hey).)).*
```

but it does not works

how should i build my query?

**Example:**

this query should return true when my sentence is:

> hi, how are you?

and must return false when my sentence is:

> hi hello hey ..

thanks in advance,

Comment: So you want to exclude all words at the same time?

Comment: thank you, yes i want to exclude all

Comment: @MostafaJamareh this would be a massive regex as it needs to make sure all `3` words are not there.You will have to put all combinations of `3` words.

Comment: Do not use a regex for this task. If you *have to* use a regex, you should "tell the boss" it is not appropriate and will cost more maintaining it than using a correct solution: 1) collect all words with say `\w+`, and then 2) checking if the array contains the forbidden words. If there are more than 1 forbidden word, the result is `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the problem is to match the string if the three words/patterns don't appear in the string together, then here is a simpler solution to the problem:

```js
^(?!(?=.*hello)(?=.*hi)(?=.*hey)).*
```

Or an alternative solution (by De Morgan's law):

```js
^(?:(?!.*hello)|(?!.*hi)|(?!.*hey)).*
```

(`not(A and B and C)` is equivalent to `not(A) or not(B) or not (C)`)

Note that it effectively scans the pattern as many times as the number of words to be checked, and it again runs into permutation problem if you want to check whether k out of n words appear in the string.